# How to hidden WhatsHelp.io javascript when media screen changing

Tags: javascript

**Hi there**

**I'm trying to change WhatsHelp.io style for mobile device,I wanna hide the fuction when screen change to under 480px but it seems to not working.
I haved try to give the div class name and set it up in css like  this, but it fales too**

```
<style>
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 480px){
  .whorwd{
    display: none;  }}</style>

<div class="whorwd">
<script type="text/javascript">
           (function  () {
            var options = {
            facebook: "***", // Facebook page ID
            line: "***", // Line QR code URL
            call_to_action: "test", // Call to action
            button_color: "#E84709", // Color of button
            position: "left", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
            order: "line,facebook", // Order of buttons         
        };
       var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "whatshelp.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = 
        url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);

    })();</script></div>
```

**It can only use in  var options when typing display:"none",
so i'm realize maybe the problem is in the javascript**

https://static.getbutton.io/widget-send-button/js/init.js

**can anyone show me how it works ? thx.**